# Missing Images in Uploads Directory (Server Only)

Tags: images, media, media-library, uploads

I recently moved a WP install from our dev server to the clients server.

Everything went fine, however, the site is missing a large amount of images. The dev site has the images in the Wordpress backend, however the images are not on the server in the appropriate `upload` directory, so the images were never uploaded to the client site.

**Example:** The backend of the dev site has an image uploaded on April 2nd. When I look in the directory `wp-content -> uploads -> 2014 -> 04` on the server, the image is not there.

I am using the ACF Gallery plugin.

Anyone have any idea where these images could be?

Comment: Did you use a plugin to move the website ? Something like "Duplicator" or did you just upload all the files via FTP to your client's server ?

Comment: I just moved everything with FTP. The site is a photography site, so its considerably large (5.5 GB!). Thought that doing it via FTP would be best...not sure if Duplicator could handle something that large?

Comment: Did you check the FTP client error messages ? Do you have "strange" characters in the image names ? Or very long names ?

Comment: No error messages from Transmit. I looked in the file manager of cpanel for the dev site as well. No luck. The 2014 -> 04 directory only has 70 images in it. If all of the images shown in the media library where in wp-uploads, there would be 250!